# How receive value from stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

ASP.NET MVC, VB.NET, SQL Server 2008 R2, Entity Framework v4

I created a stored procedure that returns an integer value

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProfileCount] 
@STARTLETTER char(1) = 'A'
AS
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM [Profils]
    WHERE LEFT(lastname,1) =  @STARTLETTER 

END
```

I imported the stored proc in EF and created a function. In that function I defined `Returns a collection of` as scalar of type `Int32` (which is consistent with what I see when I press the `[get column information]` button).

So how does this work in the controller? I've tried many things without success.

I.e.

```
Dim n As Integer = 0 
n = context.spProfileCount("Q")
```

Error:

> Value of type System.data.Objects.ObjectResults(of integer?)' can not
>   be converted to 'integer'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried what is shown in the documentation?

[ObjectResult(Of T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739113.aspx).

> ```
> // Execute the query and get the ObjectResult.
> ObjectResult<Product> queryResult = query.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
>
> // Iterate through the collection of Product items.
> foreach (Product result in queryResult)
>     Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.Name);
> ```

If you are sure you're going to have only one row, it's going to be just `queryResult.Single()`

Comment: no. is that ASP.NET MVC VB? My SP returns the value for SELECT count(*), thus yes: 1 value (of type int32).

Comment: i tried context.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of Integer)("spProfileCount @p0", "Q")  (build it with intellisesnse) but then again the same error message...

Comment: @Foxbox VB ASP.NET MVC are all not relevant to your question. So is EF. What is important is that there's a type `ObjectResults(Of integer?)` that implements `IEnumerable(Of Integer?)`. It is a collection of `Integer?`. You have to say which element of this collection you want to assign to your variable `n`. One of the ways to do it is `n = context.spProfileCount("Q").Single()`. All this is said on the documentation page.

Comment: yes: that works A-oke. tnx. IMHO the support of SP's in EF is disapointing. But maybe because that's because i'm a complete newbie . tnx for pointing me the way!

Comment: @Foxbox: not sure how much **easier** you could make this SP support - after all, your SP returns **a collection of INT** (you said so yourself and defined it to be that way); so it cannot possible be cast into a single INT as a result - right??